# How to link tests but not executables in a ROS package?

Tags: ros, cmake, rosmake, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Google Test Framework for running tests for my ROS package. I compile and link my test executable using

```
make tests
```

and run the tests by issuing command

```
make test
```

It happens, though, that other executables in that package are linked as well. Since I am usually developing test first and then adapting the source to fit that test, it is very annoying to wait for a long time for linking targets that are not required for running the test.

I do not want to hack the build system (`view $(rospack find mk)/cmake.mk`), this being inadequate and downright dangerous. Any ideas or option  I have overlooked to build only the executable added with `rosbuild_add_gtest`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9819/how-to-link-tests-but-not-executables-in-a-ros-package?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-04-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no way to do this currently, and I don't think it'll be worthwhile to implement it.  In your situation, I would do one of two things:

- comment out the executables from `CMakeLists.txt` during test development; or
- put tests in a separate package (e.g., for package `foo`, put tests in `test_foo`).

Btw, it's awesome that you're putting such effort into writing tests!

Rationale:

The `test` target can run two kinds of tests: unit tests (C++ or Python) and `rostests`.  Unit tests, which it sounds like you're using, are generally self-contained (but not always; see below).  On the other hand, it's common to use a `rostest` to verify the functionality of executables that are built by the package (e.g., see [test for topic_tools/relay](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/browser/stacks/ros_comm/trunk/test/test_topic_tools/test/relay.test)).

To support your use case, we'd need to define two categories of tests: one that wants all the executables built, and one that doesn't, with API hooks to allow the developer to say which kind of test is being declared.  We'd further have to segregate libraries from executables, to allow them to be built separately (they're currently both attached to the `ALL` target).  And then we'd likely have to retrofit existing packages that use unit tests to verify executables via fork/exec (e.g., see the [pyunit-based rospack test suite](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/browser/stacks/ros/trunk/test/test_rospack/test/utest.py)).

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3